# 4 divs and need to center 2 center divs

Tags: html, css, containers, center, inline

I have four divs inside a container like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```

I would like to keep the first and last div aligned to the edges of the screen and only center the two divs in the middle. I tried display inline block and adjusting the margins, but i just can't figure it out. Please try and enlighten me!

Kind Regards

Comment: give them different`class`es and then style the classes with css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="block left">1</div>
    <div class="block">2</div>
    <div class="block">3</div>
    <div class="block right">4</div>
</div>
```

and then this CSS

```
.container {
    display:block;
    text-align:center
}
.block {
    display:inline-block;
    border:1px solid #000;
    padding:10px;
    margin:auto
}
.left {
    float:left
}
.right {
    float:right;
}
```

you can also use first-child and last-child, but it's easier to add a class to first and last `div`

[See fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/c5na927h/)

Comment: The container should include a clear-fix to ensure it contains the floated elements.

Answer (score 0):

Try using :nth-of-type() pseudo-class allows you to select elements with a formula,like this: http://jsfiddle.net/csdtesting/11fh7suy/

```
//second div    
div.container div:nth-of-type(2) {
        background-color: #9999ff;
        text-align:center;
    }
//third div
    div.container div:nth-of-type(3) {
        background-color: #9999ff;
         text-align:center;
    }
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Very nice solution and never thought of it like that, nice to learn something new.

Comment: Yes these are very flexible!

Answer (score 0):

Adding an extra container will give you more control:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="block">1</div>
    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="block">2</div>
        <div class="block">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="block right">4</div>
</div>

.wrap{width:50px;margin:0 auto}
.block{float:left;width:25px;text-align:center}
.right{float:right}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input this is going to help me in future projects!